# What is the least labor intensive way to clean these brass door knobs?

Tags: cleaning

I have 14 of these to clean and am hoping there is some quick way to clean 30 years of accumulated kitchen muck off them.

Brasso occurred to me. But I'm wondering if there is some solution I can drop them in, and they will come out clean after a good soaking.

[image: dirty brass doorknobs]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For old brass faucets, handles, door knobs or whatever I usually drop them in a bucket of pure vinegar for a few hours - totally submerged.  After that we clean them in soap and hot water with a toothbrush.  You can add salt to add grit but that is basically it.

If you are dealing with an antique that needs a great cleaning due to some partial oxidation then you can use a cleaner like [Howard's](http://www.fashionablecanes.com/481.html?utm_source=MSN&utm_medium=cpc&utm_term=%7Bkeyword%7D%5E%7BOrderItemID%7D&utm_content=6162391060&utm_campaign=Shopping%20-%20Bing1%5E66385) (which I have used with success but no affiliation) then soap/water.

Answer (score 1):

Soak them in soapy water, then rub clean and dry with a towel. That's what I do with mucky pennies.